# How to add JSoup.jar to my android project?

Tags: android

Very basic, But I don't know, How to add JSoup.jar to my android workspace? If anyone knows, please help me?

Comment: dont quite remember but android has support for this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add [external] Jars

Comment: Really Stackoverflow is rocking. These all happened because of you guys only:)

Answer (score 11):

Create a folder named **libs** in the root of your project and put your jar files here. 
Then go to project **Properties**, under **Java Build Path** > **Libraries** click con **Add JARs...** and select you jar file, under the **libs** folder.

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder named libs in the root of your project and put your jar files here. And then **right Click** the .jar file and click **Add as Library** and Select **app** from dropdown menu and click **OK**

*Happy Coding :)*

Answer (score 2):

In **Android Studio** follow the below steps:

1. Right click on file named **app** (inside project files in the Android project view)
2. Click on **Open module settings**
3. Inside Project Structure click on the **+** (New module) symbol on  top left corner
4. Inside create new module select **.JAR/.AAR package**
5. Inside create new module select the  .jar file to be imported and click finish
6. Inside Project Structure click on **app** (below list of Modules)
7. Select Dependencies click on the **+**(Add) symbol on top right corner
8. Then select **Module dependency**
9. Select the module name to be imported from the list given in **Choose Modules** and click ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add jar in specific folder(eg: lib) than do as Francesco said
else
Just right click on project>build path>configure build path>libraries> you have some options to add jar.Which one to use upto you.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder named libs in the root of your project and put your jar files here. And then right Click the .jar file and click Add as Library and Select app from dropdown menu and click OK

This solved my problem